# Define functions to select variable in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem!

I want to define a function to select variable of a `df` 
like that

```
select_var <- function(var1, var2)
  {
    require(dplyr)
    select(df=df,var1,var2)
  }
```

using `select_var` like `select_var(var_name_1,var_name_2)`

without `""`.

I want to my df my variable !

Then I want to add `var 3` `var 4` but there are OPTIONNALS SETTING you!thank you !

Comment: How is your function meant to be different from what `select` does? Here is a good read for how to [program with `dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Why don't you use standard 1R` subsetting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enquo` and `!!` as in:

```
select_var <- function(var1, var2)
{
  require(tidyverse)
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)

  select(mtcars, !!var1, !!var2)
}

select_var(mpg, gear)

#                     mpg gear
#Mazda RX4           21.0    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0    4
#Datsun 710          22.8    4
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4    3
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7    3
#Valiant             18.1    3
# ...
```

Not sure what you mean by optionals, but maybe something like:

```
select_var <- function(...)
{
  require(tidyverse)
  vars <- quos(...)

  select(mtcars, !!!vars)
}

select_var(mpg)
select_var(mpg, gear)
select_var(mpg, gear, cyl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select rows from the same or different dataframes by indexing with the which() function. You can use logical operators to do it across variables.

```
which(df[,var1] == df[,var1] &
      df[,var2] == df[,var2])
```

The which() function will return an index of rows that meat the functions criteria. If you want it to return rows from your dataframe you can do something like this:

```
df[
   which(df[,var1] == df[,var1] &
         df[,var2] == df[,var2])
  ,]
```

This will call the row numbers in df that meet your criteria.

Comment: No this is not the problem !!  I want to subset my dataframe !

Comment: Ok. I am not really sure what you mean. Can you edit the question to be more specific?